# Jamie Rumbelow's MY_Model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question I'm using Jamie Rumbelow's `MY_Model` as my model and I'm trying to figure out how I can add a field from a separate table.

Site Pages- `id`, `page_name`, `page_slug`, `date_created`, `author_id`, `sort_order`

I do a get all function run to get all the records of the site pages. It returns the array correctly however when it does it returns the value of the `author_id` which I need it to get the actual user's name from a user's table.

Users - `id`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`

So the `author_id` equals the `id` of the user table and it needs to select the first name and last name. I'm not sure how to pull this off with this `MY_Model`.

Has anyone else tried doing this before?

Comment: ask it to Jamie lol, sorry it was to clear, i'm joking :D

Comment: You mean [this code](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model)?

Comment: Excuse me complex857?

Comment: @KevinSmith Err, i don't think you have anything to apologize for, just wanted to make sure we are talking about the same thing (-:. A yes or a link to the right code would be much enough.

Comment: You require a 'Join' between the two tables, which doesn't appear to be available in that code. You will have to use the resulting ID to do another call to the user table using the get_by() method.

Comment: It has an area on the doc for relationships but I'm not understanding it. https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jamie Rumbelow's base model supports really basic relationships.

Your page model should define the relationship:

```
class Page_model extends MY_Model
{
    public $belongs_to = array('author');
}
```

As should your author model:

```
class Author_model extends MY_Model
{
    public $has_many = array('posts');
}
```

Now, you should be able to retrieve the posts with associated authors:

```
$pages = $this->page->with('author')->get_all();
```

This is all in the [documentation](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model).